# to make value unchanged if the if condition is false in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

to make value unchanged if the if condition in excel formula remains unchanged

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D8088,Shopify!N:N,0)),"TRUE","FALSE")

I want the values to be unchanged if condition is false in excel

Comment: You lost me, mate. Which value? Which If condition? Which change? Is there a significance to your repeating your formula twice?

Comment: @Variatus. Thanks for your reply. Let me simplify this =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(8,8)),"TRUE","FALSE"). If 8=8 then it will paste true in the column. if this condition gets false. It will paste FALSE. but my question is if this if condition is false then it should not change the value of the column.

Comment: Just replace the false with the cell number containing the original value.

Comment: @SolarMike  Thanks for your reply. I have tried to replace the cell number but it gives reference error.

Comment: Then there is either an error in that cell or you have not stated it correctly. Example : IF(A3=B3,A3*2,B3) will if true put A3*2 and when false B3...

Comment: @Varun Kumar There is no "value of the column". The formula sets the value of each cell in the column individually according to the formula in it. For this purpose it has two choices, either TRUE or FALSE. The "value of the column" will therefore be set (not changed) in every case. There is no "original value" which might be left unchanged.

Comment: @VariatusThats what the problem is. But how can we solve that one

Comment: @SolarMike I have tried it nothing works

Comment: Show, by editing your question, what you have tried based on the suggestions you received - there is an error somewhere, also show example data...